# code formatting at build time

Tags: maven-2, ant, formatting, build

can anyone suggest me a plugin/tool that can perform a code formatting at build time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Jalopy Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jalopy-maven-plugin/) has a [`jalopy:format`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jalopy-maven-plugin/format-mojo.html) mojo that can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming for Java, there are many that you can plugin to Eclipse like CheckStyle, Jalopy, Findbugs

These can also run with Ant/Maven as part of the build

Comment: CheckStyle and FindBugs don't format the code, they just report on a configurable list of formatting problems and / or coding errors.  Jalopy is a good option, though.